# Bypass "user gesture" requirement when testing "beforeunload" dialogue in Cypress

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, cypress

I am trying to write a Cypress test to validate that a `beforeunload` dialogue appears when a user tries to navigate away from an incomplete form.

When a user tries to leave a page after interacting with a form,  my site activates a `beforeunload` dialogue to warn them unsaved data may be lost. Everything works fine when I test the behavior manually but When I try to write a test in Cypress I get

`'[Intervention] Blocked attempt to show a 'beforeunload' confirmation panel for a frame that never had a user gesture since its load. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5082396709879808'`.

This is after typing in various fields and simulating `click()` events. It seams that JS does not trigger a true "user gesture" . I understand why Chrome does this but I would hope there would still be a way to write tests. I've found workarounds for a similar problem with video playback @ https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2376. But this does not seam to work for "beforeunload". None of the flags I found here seam to work https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

```
    on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, args) => {
      if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
        // Mac/Linux
        args.push('--disable-gesture-requirement-for-presentation')
      }
      return args
    })
```

Hoping there might be a work around. Can I either simulate an actual "gesture" in Cypress or disable the requirement in Chrome? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cypress, but can you send Window Messages to Chrome to simulate user mouse input?

Comment: @Dai I've filled in a number of fields and executed `click()` events using Cypress. It's very similar to JQuery. But It seams like JS events don't trigger a "user gesture"

Comment: Right - that’s why I said “window message”, it’s an OS-level feature. See Win32’s `SendMessage` for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm actually on a Mac and cannot really find equivalent functionality to the Windows article you posted. And I haven't touched C++ in more than a decade. Also, not sure how to accomplish this as part of a Cypress test run. It does have a `task` feature for running Node.js files, but nothing for running native OS code that I can see. But gives me some new ideas at least. Thanks again.